# nomodule and "type="module" works differently for IE 11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I was testing the functionality of `nomodule` and `type="module"` in an app. I used chrome which only downloaded the file in `type="module"` tag, which was expected. But when I tested it in IE 11, to my amusement files where downloaded from both the script tags.

I have attached the images for reference. Please help me understand this behaviour.

### index.html

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>custom-element demo</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script nomodule src="http://localhost:85/email-compose-legacy.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:85/email-compose.min.js"></script>

<email-compose-legacy></email-compose-legacy>
```

[image: network tab in chrome]

[image: network tab in IE 11]

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=nomodule

Comment: See https://github.com/philipwalton/webpack-esnext-boilerplate/issues/1

Comment: I cannot see any solutions in the given links, If you see so please describe the solution

Comment: The solution is not to use or support IE in 2020 ;)

Comment: @Dominic very unhelpful comment.  I think it's fair to say that other than very small companies or one-man-band teams, those of us here with our hands dirty in the technical detail are unlikely to _also_ be influencing which browsers the business chooses to support.  While your comment may have been in jest, it doesn't help the OP.  [In case you're wondering why I don't have a solution to offer, I'm here in the same plight as the OP].

Answer (score 1):

I think that's due to the different JS engines used in different browsers.

From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), we can see that the `nomodule` and `type="module"` attributes only ensure if the scripts will be excuted but can't ensure if they will be downloaded:

> `nomodule`
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate that the script should not be **executed** in browsers that support ES2015 modules.
>
> `module`: Causes the code to be treated as a JavaScript module.

So we only need to ensure the `type="module"` script won't be excuted in IE and the `nomodule` script will be excuted in IE which is the opposite in Chrome.

Return to the JS engine, [Chrome uses V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) as the JS engine and [IE and Edge Legacy use Chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JScript_engine)) as the JS engine. You'll find that the scripts will also be both downloaded in Edge Legacy. So I think that's the different JS engines lead to the different behaviors.